# Angular 2 doesn't import Bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

Directly from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

> Let's add the stylesheet.
>
> Open a terminal window in the application root folder and enter the command:
>
> npm install bootstrap --save
>
> Open index.html and add the following link to the head.
>
> link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

However, i keep getting 404

> GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

It works when i add the script with the online address, but why does angular fails to find the path to my file?

Comment: Can you check if css exists at that location on file system. Are you using angular cli to build ? If yes then you need copy this to vendor and adjust the path

Comment: Yes, the file is there. By adding to the vendor do you mean to vendorNpmFiles? i added this line there 'bootstrap/**/*' and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, Now check if file is there in dist/vendor. If it is then change link to link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is working when `index.html` is in the same directory as `node_modules`.

To add bootstrap from angular-CLI put

`'bootstrap/dist/**/*.+(js|css.map|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)'`

in `angular-cli-build.js` and run `ng build`

Answer (score 21):

If you're using **angular-cli**, you can go to `root/styles.css` and add this line

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Or go to `.angular-cli.json` and modify `styles`

```
"styles": [
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"styles.css"
]
```

Comment: This answer is still valid one year later. Well done!

Answer (score 4):

If you use angular-cli after the webpack transition, add

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

to the `styles` array in `angular-cli.json` like:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
```

If you also use bootstrap javascript, add those files to the `scripts` array.

Comment: It is recommended to have Bootstrap CSS to the apps[0].styles; e.i. "styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "styles.css"
], refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli

Comment: @MartinW What is the difference between adding it in the angular-cli.json or just importing it in a sass/scss file (if that is used)?

Comment: Wonder, why no one upvote this? this is the easiest way. but i did have to redo "ng serve" for the changes to be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

or

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular cli for build hence you need to copy bootstrap to vendor directory by updating `vendorNpmFiles` in angularcli-build.js

```
bootstrap/**/*.*
```

Now you need to update link of index.html to pick css from vendor

```
< link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```