# How to use Bootstrap css Library in Angular 2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I know that if I want to include bootstap to my angular2 app, the simplest way is to include css/js to my header...

What if I have 2 routes /bootstrap & /foundation that each one has different css framework...

The main index.html is one file with specific header... What can i do to have multiple ?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292438/how-to-use-bootstrap-css-library-in-angular-2-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download bootstrap.

```
npm install bootstrap —save
```

Then in style.css

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```