# angular1 bootstrap does not support in angular2

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am working on converting the AngularJS application to Angular 2 application.Bootstrap functionality is not working in Angular 2 which was used in AngularJS .Is there is any alternative for Angular 2 bootstrap?

```
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">OrangeTestDefaultActivity<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a ng-click="handle_url('Screen_1050')">Label</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="handle_url('Screen_1100')">Become</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io

Comment: normal bootstrap is not working in angular2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Bootstrap css Library in Angular 2 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292438/how-to-use-bootstrap-css-library-in-angular-2-project)

Comment: Are you using `Angular-Cli`? If you are its really easy.

Answer (score 0):

In your Index html file, import

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```