# Unable to use Bootstrap library in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Header Code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

angular.json code

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "../prab/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
```

I am unable to see the bootstrap css in output window

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Bootstrap css Library in Angular 2 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292438/how-to-use-bootstrap-css-library-in-angular-2-project)

Comment: I put the image as included in the question, not just a link.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't want to update the angular.json file, you can instead update the styles.css file as follows:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";

div.card-header {
 font-size: large;
}

div.card {
  margin-top: 10px
}

.table {
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
]
```

It is already answered, see this

[How to use Bootstrap css Library in Angular 2 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292438/how-to-use-bootstrap-css-library-in-angular-2-project)