# what are ngx bootstrap, ng bootstrap, md bootrap and angular material design?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I am new to angular and have intermediate knowledge about Bootstrap 4. But I am confused about using bootstrap in my angular project. I was using normal Bootstrap 4. But for some of features like carousel for multi card items in a row , I am struggling with normal bootstrap. But now I am confused with which bootstrap should I use in my angular project for best practice. What are all these angular material design, ng bootstrap, ngx bootstrap, md bootstrap and which organization or community build and maintain these?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292438/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-an-angular-project/43254064. Material Design is Google's Design framework, you probably don't want to use it with Bootstrap, choose one or the other.

Comment: I have gone through this but that was not helpful. My question is something different from what is asked and answered there.

Comment: The basic answers to your questions are Twitter runs the Bootstrap project and Google the Material Design project and Angular. Search for the framework you want to use and Angular will have many ways to implement that (the question I posted DOES relate to your question). If you want a specific answer you will need to pose a specific question with actual code.

Answer (score -3):

ngx-bootstrap is an OSS project, which basically maintained by Valor Software team, and, the project contributors

feel free to ask any questions in github repo: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap, or, in slack: https://ngx-home.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtNTExMTY5MzcwMTM0LWVjZGU2MjI4MTVhMGVlMTc2OWRiMzA0NzBhNDU5YzQ0MDM3MWI5NzJjZTUzNzIxZmNjYmFlMjU2MzE0YmY0NWY#/

Comment: It's not a complete answer.